# Conversion failed when converting date with DATEADD

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

I am using this query:

```
INSERT INTO Registro_EQ (Codigo, Fechtran, Fechaini, Fechaexp, IDCONF, Descripcion, Marca, Modelo, Serie, ConLista, Porcentaje_cl, SinLista, Porcentaje_sl, Movible,
            Porcentaje_mv, Edificio, Porcentaje_ed, Automatico, Exceso, Porcentaje_ex, Asignacion, Estatus, IDUsuario)
SELECT DATEADD(year, 1, Fechaini) as Fecha, DATEADD(year, 1, Fechaexp) as Fecha2,
       [Codigo] , [Fechtran], [IDCONF], [Descripcion], [Marca], [Modelo], [Serie], [ConLista], [Porcentaje_cl], [SinLista], [Porcentaje_sl], [Movible],
       [Porcentaje_mv], [Edificio], [Porcentaje_ed], [Automatico], [Exceso], [Porcentaje_ex], [Asignacion], [Estatus], [IDUsuario]
  FROM [Pru].[dbo].[Registro_EQ]
  WHERE Fechaini >= '2016-01-01' AND Fechaini < '2017-01-01'
```

When I run send me the following message:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I know that is by datetime, but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: You need to identify the data types of all fields that you think are dates. For example, what datatype is `Fechaini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order on Insert Into is Codigo, Fechtran, Fechaini, Fechaexp, IDCONF and in the Select the order is different, Fecha, Fecha2, Codigo, Fechtran, IDCONF.

So you're most likely inserting data to wrong columns.

Comment: I hope that was what you were trying to say. It was so unclear so I rewrote some of it.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your problem is that `Fechaini` is stored as a character string rather than a date.  This is the wrong data type.  You should use the appropriate built-in data types, unless you have a good reason for not doing so.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can see the values that are causing a problem:

```
select Fechaini
from [Pru].[dbo].[Registro_EQ]
where try_convert(date, Fechaini) is null;
```

You should then fix your data.  The best way would be to change the data to the correct type (a date or datetime type).

Answer (score 0):

1st execute the select query without the insert, if the error disappear then you are inserting wrong format date from the select to your target table

2nd if you got the error from the select query, you must make sure the format of the field "fechaini" is date, if it's not make sure all data contained are in date format and shouldnt contains empty string.